# Installing a SQL Compact-based .NET app

Tags: .net, installation, sql-server-ce

Is there a way to have an application access a SQL Compact database file without having to install the SQL Compact installer as well?  I don't want to have a separate installer run when the user installs my program.  Can I get by with just some well placed DLL's in my application's folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Private deployment of the runtime within your app is possible and avoids the need for admin privileges.

Here is the [documentation for 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983326.aspx) and for the [previous versions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983326(VS.80).aspx) as they are somewhat different.